# How can be accessed to Parent variable from child Object if it was replaced in Child?

Tags: php, oop, parent-child

I have two classes - Parent "First" with variable $number, and I have Child class "Second" in where property $number is changed.

How can access to Parent variable from child Object if it was replaced in Child?

We can't change properties and method which we have now.

```
class First {

  protected $number = "First";

  protected function getNumber() {

     return $this->number;

  }

}

class Second extends First {

  protected $number = "Second";

  protected $count = "One More";

}

$first = new First;

$second = new Second;

// must show "First"
echo $second->getNumber();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getNumber() method is declared as protected so your example code will cause a Fatal Error.

To quote php docs :

> Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class
>   itself and by inherited and parent classes.

Link : http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

So, you would first need to create your own custom class that extends Second, and either override the getNumber method or create another method which instantiates the parent class in order to return its $number value.Your method should be declared as public to be able to access it from outside of the class. See example below:

```
class First {

  protected $number = "First";

  protected function getNumber() {

     return $this->number;

  }

}

class Second extends First {

  protected $number = "Second";

  protected $count = "One More";

}

class CustomClass extends Second {


  public function callSecondClassParentGetNumberMethod() {

    $parentClass=get_parent_class('Second');
    $parent=new $parentClass;
    //or if you know the parent class just call it directly:
    //$parent =new First;
     return $parent->getNumber();

  }

}


$customClass = new CustomClass;

// shows "First"
echo $customClass->callSecondClassParentGetNumberMethod();
```

Comment: Thank you, this is refreshing for my mind...
Sorry, but I can't increase your reputation, because I have not permission for this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, **matwr** so much... you make my day!

I just made small changes in your solution, and this works perfect.

```
class First {

protected $number = "First";

protected function getNumber() {

    return $this->number;

}
```

}

class Second extends First {

```
protected $number = "Second";

public function getNumber() {

    $parent = new First;

    return $parent->getNumber();

}
```

}

$first = new First;

$second = new Second;

// shows "First"
echo $second->getNumber();